# Why does it return true when the not display is used in the try and catch?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

ok so I am wanting to know if there is an email in the table, so I have written a method to do just that.  In the table there is nothing at all so why does it return true?

```
private bool FilterUserTableByEmail(string email)
{
    FilterUserTableByWebElement(_regRep.FilterByNameEmail(), email);

    try
    {
        //_regRep.emailIDInTable(email);

        if (!_regRep.noDataFoundText.Displayed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was found in the table.");

        }
        return true;

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
    {
        // the search result did not come back in the table - return false
        Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was NOT found in the table..." + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code after the IF will always execute.

Comment: So whats the solution?

Comment: Move the return true inside the if, and return false after the if.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `return` statement to inside the `if`:

```
if (!_regRep.noDataFoundText.Displayed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was found in the table.");
    return true; 
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

Which can be simplified (the `else` is redundant):

```
if (!_regRep.noDataFoundText.Displayed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was found in the table.");
    return true; 
}
return false;
```

Doing this means that the method returns `true` if an email is found, otherwise it returns `false`.  What you had originally **always** returned `true`, unless an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Just added this after if statement :**

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was NOT found in the table..." + ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

Full Code :

```
private bool FilterUserTableByEmail(string email)
{
    FilterUserTableByWebElement(_regRep.FilterByNameEmail(), email);

    try
    {
        //_regRep.emailIDInTable(email);
        if (!_regRep.noDataFoundText.Displayed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was found in the table.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was NOT found in the table..." + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            // the search result did not come back in the table - return false
            Console.WriteLine("Email for " + email + " was NOT found in the table..." + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
}
```